# Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported... Error(too many Huffman tables)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gnu

Today, I encountered the following error upon booting Grub:

> GNU GRUB version 2.06
>
> Minimal BASH like line editing is supported.For the first word,TAB
> lists possible device or file completion.Anywhere else TAB lists
> possible device or file completions.
>
> grub>

Instead of being directed towards the usual graphical interface, I was presented with a CLI, asking me for input. I have tried solving the issue with advice given from geeksforgeeks by executing the following commands:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt3)
grub> set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
grub> insmod normal
grub> normal
```

But after this it throws an error saying `error: jpeg: too many Huffman tables.`

Actually what happened was I was trying to change the background of the gnu grub by gnu customizer app in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't let any "app" altering my grub. Since no one knows what was changed, your best bet is to get the [Ubuntu boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) disk. Burn it on a USB (maybe using a live image), then start the "Boot-repair" live disk, fix your Grub.

When successful, start your device, login and remove that "Grub fixing app".
It is not difficult to change the background of plymouth (the grub background screen as you call it) - but do it manually.

Comment: I tried using a live USB but is not working because I never set up the boot settings to be F12

Comment: Pls say what can I do now

Comment: Enter your bios and setup that you want to start from USB. Later you can revert it again if necessary

Comment: Thank you for your reply .But the problem with my system is no matter how many times I reboot the system it always comes to grub terminal

Comment: And I think for going to bios you should set up in windows command prompt or the Linux 
terminal so that while booting pressing the assigned function key(F2/F11/F12) will get you into bios(Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: And I have no way of accessing either of them 

Comment: And it always comes to like a grub cli not grub menu

Comment: Why don't you [search](https://www.cgdirector.com/how-to-enter-bios/) This has nothing to do with Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you,I entered the bios , plugged the live USB, used boot repair, and that worked.Thanks again